# Which fraction is more

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me prove why

$$1-\left(\frac{x-10}{y}\right) \gt 1-\left(\frac{x}{y+10}\right)$$

when $y < x$.

I have no idea how to show this algebraically so i'd really like some guidance.

Comment: Are there any boundries on x and y?

Comment: I have updated your question for display style. Please make sure it is still the same. `:)`.

Comment: This isn't true in general; consider $x=40, y=20$.

Comment: And adding the condition $y \lt x$ doesn't help.

Comment: $x=0$ and $y=-1$ gives $-9>1$, which is false. So give us some extra boundaries on $x$ and $y$      XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the fractions with the leading $1-$
$$1-\left(\frac{x-10}{y}\right) \stackrel{?}{\gt} 1-\left(\frac{x}{y+10}\right)
\\\left(\frac{y-x+10}{y}\right) \stackrel{?}{\gt} \left(\frac{y+10-x}{y+10}\right)$$
Now the numerators are the same.  We can see that there is no clear comparison between them.

If $y-x+10 \gt 0$ and $y \gt 0$ the left will be larger because both are positive and the left denominator is smaller.

If $y-x+10 \lt 0$ and $y \gt 0$ the left will be smaller because both are negative and the left denominator is smaller.

And other cases depending on $y, y+10$.

Comment: In the case of $y - x + 10 \lt 0$, the left will be smaller, not larger.

Comment: @DylanSp: Oops, missed the edit when copying.  Fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We'll try $x=-11$ and $y=-7$. Now
$$-2=1−\frac{x−10}{y}> 1-\frac{x}{y+10}=\frac{14}{3}$$
So actually, your statement is false.

Comment: Your math on the left side of the inequality is wrong; $1 - \frac{-11 - 10}{-7} = 1 - 3 = -2$.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Fixed it.

Comment: I'm not proving the statement, I'm disproving it

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the expressions, we get the equivalent inequality
$$
\frac{y-x+10}y\gt\frac{y+10-x}{y+10}
$$
This inequality is true if $y\not\in\{0,10,x-10\}$ and one and only one of the following are true
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\small{\text{1.}}&x\lt y+10&\text{both numerators are positive}\\
\text{2.}&-10\lt y\lt0&\text{denominators have different signs}
\end{array}
$$
Unfortunately, there are many values of $(x,y)$ in which neither is true, e.g. $(12,1)$, and many in which both are true, e.g. $(1,-1)$. Therefore, without some other restriction on $(x,y)$, the inequality is not true in general.